# CSS solution for random gap in unordered list

Tags: css

I have 2 gaps in my unordered list that I cannot find the problem source or a proper solution to fix it.

An `element.style {clear: left;}` applied to the `<li>` tag immediately to the right of the space seems to clear the space to the left, but another randomly appears further down the page.

I am sure that the fix is simple, but all of the information that I can find seems to fit around multi-sized link images or a pattern of space.  On the affected page all images should be the same size, 150x150, and the gaps seem to only affect 2 links out of 25+ listed.  I nevertheless tinkered with their findings to see if it lead me to a solution, the closest I came was the above.

The affected page is [here](http://www.mjclookbooks.com/mjc-lines/).

The page code and CSS are [here](http://pastebin.com/dWX8HFTP).

I appreciate any advice that can be given, on how to properly resolve this issue.  My solution seems to only mask the true nature of my problem.

Comment: that's because third element has only one line of description, hence is shorter than the first two. that's why the fourth one is placed under the third element. Moreover, the whole list is very poorly styled...

Comment: Thanks @Lordex I see now why they are different heights. Thanks for your feedback, I am new and have so much to learn.  How might I better style my list?  Can you point me in the direction of an article for proper styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this rule:

```
#list-1 >li:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: this won't work because the gap is dependend on whether previous items have different height

Comment: @LorDex - Before downvoting you should test the code, which in this case absolutely works since the items are floated.

Comment: before you post answer, try to fiddle with other list items description

Comment: @LorDex - Why do I need to create a fiddle when I tested my code with the OP's actual site code?

Comment: @j08691  - This was the solution to my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not really for me to comment, @onerockscott, but... I think the alternative answer I have posted below is more... scalable... than this one. No matter - all the best!

Comment: @Rounin - Personally I think hard-coding the width and min-height rules is less flexible, but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#list-1 #desc {
    width: 150px;
    min-height:44px;
}
```

Comment: As @LorDex pointed out in the comment beneath your question, all the `#desc`s need to have a uniform height. Having some `#desc`s shorter than others, interferes with the desired `float:` behaviour.

Comment: Incidentally, `id` is a unique identifier. Rather than repeatedly using `id="desc"`, you ought to be using `class="desc"`.

Comment: `min-hieght: 44px;` didn't work for me but `min-hieght: 50px;` did.

Comment: Great to hear! The `44px` wasn't really the important bit. The important bit was establishing a uniform minimum height for `#desc`.

Comment: Thanks @Rounin I see now why they are different heights. I am new and have so much to learn.